# Logistic regression with multicategory categorical explanatory variables

Tags: regression, probability, logistic, predictor

I'd like to perform logistic regression with some categorical explanatory variables with more categories than just binary 0/1. Is this possible and why?

I am inclined to think that this would give just the wrong result because of the geometric intuition, however most opinions online say that explanatory variables can be discrete/categorical (although I don't see any mentions of more categories). For 0/1 this is fine because the distances between 0 and 1 is easy.

If I have even 3 categories 0/1/2, it's unclear if 1-0 is the same as 2-1.

One thought I had is to do a sort of one-vs-all thing for the explanatory variables. So if I had one parameter that can on 3 categories A/B/C I remake this into 3 separate parameters:

```
A: 0/1
B: 0/1
C: 0/1
```

Where 0 is not belonging to the letter class and 1 is belonging to the letter class.

Background: My dependent variable should be binary. I really wanted to use logistic regression because of the probability interpretation. If you can recommend another method that can output a probability estimate (instead of only classification) that takes in categorical explanatory variables, that would also be helpful.

Comment: It's fine: logistic regression requires only that the logit of the probability of "success" be a sum of parameters multiplied by explanatory variables, where the explanatory variables can be anything you like - $x_1$, $x_1^2$, $x_1x_2$, splines, &c. The only thing wrong with your coding scheme is that everything has to belong to some category,  so you don't need three parameters for the categorical variable in addition to an intercept - take say A as the reference level, & then parameters for B & C represent changes in the logit going from A to B, or from A to C.

Comment: Yes, thanks for catching that typo. Fixed in the question.

Comment: .I'm not sure I understand what you mean by the "reference level". An example would be I have a explanatory variable "color" which can be "blue", "red", "green". My coding scheme basically says that I would change this into 3 binary parameters: red/notred, blue/notblue and green/notgreen. Assuming that only these 3 colors exist in the world.

Comment: I'm off out, but Google "coding categorical variables" or look [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/contrast_coding.htm), or wait for a proper answer.

Comment: *"My coding scheme basically says that I would change this into 3 binary parameters: red/notred, blue/notblue and green/notgreen. Assuming that only these 3 colors exist in the world."* Correct. But when fitting the model, you'll only need two of the three colors. The one that didn't get in is the reference category, it will be captured by the intercept.

Answer (score 3):

The comments from @Scortchi and @Penguin_Knight essentially say it all. Any generalized linear model can handle categorical predictors, and several options exist to accommodate different styles of comparison. Dummy coding is probably simplest, and would only require you to drop one of your binary parameters corresponding to your choice of a reference group. Scortchi's link to the UCLA Statistical Consulting Group's [*R Library: Contrast Coding Systems for categorical variables*](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/contrast_coding.htm) page covers this and many other coding options nicely with [r](/questions/tagged/r) code included.

Sorry I don't have more to add; it seems you already understand the method, and I don't know of any other methods to recommend for your specific purpose, nor do I see the problem with the geometric intuition...Feel free to expand on that though.